# cant load react in electronjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-packager

Here is my package.js file

```html
{
  "name": "cabed",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "electron-forge": "^5.2.4",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^17.1.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "main": "public/electron.js",
 "homepage": "./",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"cross-env BROWSER=none npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:3000 && electron .",
    "eb": "electron-packager C:/Users/user/cabed cddf --platform=win32 --arch=x64"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "electron": "^22.1.0",
    "wait-on": "^7.0.1"
  },
  "config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {},
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "stock_trading_app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin",
            "linux",
            "win32"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The generated exe with electron builder which i ran with

```html
npm run eb
```

the exe generated by code above
does not render the react app inside the opened windows app.

Here is my app js

```html
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{justifyContent:'center',alignContent:'center',alignItems:'center'}}>
    <div className="App">
     
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
         Sasdsad
        </p>
        <p>
         Sasdsad
        </p>
    </div></div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my electron.js looks like this under public directory.

```html
const path = require('path');

const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const isDev = require('electron-is-dev');

function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // and load the index.html of the app.
  // win.loadFile("index.html");
  win.loadURL(
    isDev
      ? 'http://localhost:3000'
      : `file://${path.join(__dirname, "./index.html")}`
  );
  // Open the DevTools.
  if (isDev) {
    win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' });
  }
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed, except on macOS. There, it's common
// for applications and their menu bar to stay active until the user quits
// explicitly with Cmd + Q.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

When running npm start first, then the exe renders react page inside window.
I need some configuration probably but i could not found it yet.

Comment: Can you show the place where you start your electron application?

Comment: npm run dev command opens a window which loads react app successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said it works when you start your server first, I assume you're using the `localhost` URL both in dev and in prod. When your app is packaged, you should load the file in your window and not the local URL:

```
const { app } = require("electron");

const windowURL = app.isPackaged
  ? `file://${path.join(__dirname, "./index.html")}`
  : "http://localhost:3000/";

mainWindow.loadURL(windowURL);
```

The path when your app is packaged might be different depending on your file structure and your build/package configurations. Also, don't forget to add [`"homepage": "./"`](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson) on your `package.json` or you may get a blank page.

Comment: Added homepage and updated my electron.js file as you suggested, still a blank page appears. I edited updated codes above and added my public/electron.js file. No error shown after running builded exe and React App appears as header but still a plank page inside the window.

Comment: @alperyolcu Check that you have no error in the dev console and that the paths are correct in the Network tab.

Comment: No error for both console and network tabs. When reload app from top bar loads index js under resources/app/public/index.js, after force reload, loads index.js successfully but failed to load manifest.json

Comment: @alperyolcu You need to build your react app before packaging and then use the `index.html` in the `build` folder for the packaged app.